# Avoid text to change in disagreement with collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Collapse JS from Bootstrap and want the collapse button text to change upon clicking.

I'm using a very simple JS to change the text of the button when clicked but it has a problem: If I click too fast on the button, the text changes but the collapse doesn't follow. So I have the text reverted (show for hide and hide for show behaviour).

```
jQuery(function () {
    return $('.collapse-link').click(function () {
        var $this;
        $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('collapsed');
        if ($this.hasClass('collapsed')) {
            $this.text('Show');
        } else {
            $this.text('Hide');
        }
    });
});
```

This is the fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/9x80309y/1](https://jsfiddle.net/9x80309y/1/)

Try clicking very fast on the Show button. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please see bootstrap collapse events documentation.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events)

Bootstrap collapse JS will fire events on state complete so you can use these to make sure your button always has the right text depending on which state the collapse is in.

```
$('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   // When collapse event has gotten to hidden state, change button text
   $('.collapse-link').html('Show');
});

$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
   // When collapse event has gotten to shown state, change button text
   $('.collapse-link').html('Hide');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hpeinar/9x80309y/3/

Comment: Thanks Henrik! Didn't noticed that section in the docs. It did solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't recreate, but try this as a way to make sure you're in the right state and avoid your race condition (most likely).

```
jQuery(function () {
    return $('.collapse-link').click(function () {
        var $this;
        $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.hasClass('collapsed')) {
            $this.text('Show');
            $this.addClass('collapsed');
        } else {
            $this.text('Hide');
            $this.removeClass('collapsed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent the race :/